# Python: Scrape all of the names of the officeholders in the tables being referenced in a list of urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, find, screen-scraping, page-inspector

I am trying to get python to give me the names of State Senators and Represenatives on Ballotpedia. However, the code I put together is only giving me the title I requested from the url but I am not getting any names. Here is my current python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_State_Senate', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_House_of_Representatives']

temp_dict = {}

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in 
soup.select("table.bptable gray sortable tablesorter 
jquery-tablesorter a")]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, 
orient='index').transpose()
```

I believe my error is in this line:

```
temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in 
soup.select("table.bptable gray sortable tablesorter 
jquery-tablesorter a")]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the relevant part(s) of the HTML?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to target this:  <table class="bptable gray sortable tablesorter tablesorter-default tablesorter621a64124691c jquery-tablesorter" id="officeholder-table"...>

Answer (score 1):

The index of both the tables is the same from the pages. Simply use pandas read_html to get the tables and concat all the results:-

```
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_State_Senate', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_House_of_Representatives']

appended_data = []

for page in urls:
    df = pd.read_html(page)[3]
    appended_data.append(df)

appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
```